# wpf ListView change selection overlay

Tags: wpf, listview, selection, uwp

I want to have a `ListView` where I can select an item. Selecting the item changes the background color, and changes the color of some items in the `ListViewItem`.

I have looked on SO, but only found answers concerning removing the selection overlay. Is there a way to change what happens when an item is selected?

Comment: You need to better explain what you want, ideally with some code. Are you looking for an MVVM solution, or just code-behind? Help us out here a bit...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try Triggers:

```
<ListBox>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Where do I put this in my XAML tree? I can't seem to find where this fits. Sorry, I'm pretty new to windows development.